# How to count the checkboxes which are checked and not disabled in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to find the count of the checkboxes which are checked and not disabled in jquery.
I tried usingthe statement
 $(".chkbox:not(:disabled)").attr('checked', this.checked); but this is not maintaing the checkbox state properly

Comment: I tried this statement $(".chkbox:not(:disabled)").attr('checked', this.checked);

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
var boxes = $('input[type="checkbox"]').filter(function() {
    return this.checked && !this.disabled;
}).length;
```

Answer (score 8):

```
$('input[type=checkbox]:checked').not(':disabled').length;
```

Comment: Have you tried that??? :D

Comment: @Sergio What's funny about it? http://api.jquery.com/disabled-selector/

Answer (score 1):

```
$("input[type='checkbox']:checked").not("input[disabled='disabled']");
```

Answer (score 1):

Javascript

```
var $input = $('input[type=checkbox]');
alert($input.not(':disabled').filter(':checked').length);
```

HTML

```
  <input type="checkbox" checked="checked">
  <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" disabled="disabled">
  <input type="checkbox">
```

http://jsbin.com/idifot/1/edit